# Run a Flow on a Folder in a SP Online Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I would like to create a Flow that can be run on Folders in a Document Library (this includes sub-folders).

In the Modern Team Site experience currently the Flow button only appears when you are either inside the Document Library or when you Select a File in the Document Library. If you select a Folder, the Flow button disappears..

I would love if:

(1) Users to be able to manually trigger a flow on a given Folder or Sub-Folder in a document library.

(2) Even better (if possible), I would like this specific flow I create to be only visible in a specific Folder's Sub-Folders.

Many thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do in the Flow?

Comment: I have a Sub-Folder of a Folder, I want the button to "Send to other location" to appear when you only select the Sub-Folder, when clicked, I want a form to appear for the user to enter metadata, then the folder is moved to a document library in another site collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to move the sub-folder to another document library I would recommend using document sets instead of sub-folders.  Then you can run your flow on the document set to move it.